# Jenkins Plugin, share local configuration

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a plugin with two builders (BuilderA & BuilderB)

Each builder has its own local config for the step and dropdown field called 'server', which default value is 'Defualt' and then options that have been defined from the global. These steps can be run independently (so BuilderA doesn't need BuilderB ...) or togher BuilderA then B.

When running e.g. BuilderA then BuilderB, if BuilderA has had the server set you should be able to just leave BuilderB as default and it should pick up the server used from BuilderA. Now I've gotten close with:

```
Project p = (Project)build.getProject();
List<Builder> blist = p.getBuilders();
for(Builder b : blist){
    //somethinghere
}
```

From debugging the blist contains the builders for that build and in the for loop b is the specific builder in this case BuilderA. I can get the name to check its correct builder, but can not get the server value (though I can see it from the debug).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

Check that b is the class you were looking for (example BuilderA) then:

```
 BuilderA a = (BuilderA)b;
```

You can now access the getter methods from your other builder